# Finding optimal points in contours produced by ListContourPlot

Tags: plotting, list-manipulation, mathematical-optimization

I have a list of data for use in ListContourPlot in the form of:

```
data={{x1,y1,v1},{x2,y2,v2},...};
```

Let's say the values of *v* range from -1 to 1. When plotted, it is clear there are optimal points on the contours that are produced (e.g, for contour 0.5, there is a minimal value of *x*).

Is there an automatic way to obtain such values from the plot (i.e. as opposed to using plot coordinates)? If so, would there dependence on the interpolation order?

**UPDATE:** The data would look something like this:
[image: data example]

Imagine I have a ton of these plots and want to find the minimal value of *x* on the 0.5 contour for each of them.

Comment: "I have a list of data..." - then, could you maybe post it in [Pastebin](https://pastebin.com/)?

Comment: Like, do you mean you want to select only those sub-lists where `x` falls under some condition? :s

Comment: @e.doroskevic Not really; I want to find the _interpolated_ value of `x` from the contour produced in Mathematica that meets my criteria, in this case the minimal interpolated value.

Comment: The plot shows `x` asa single-valued function of `y` for each contour.  May the reader assume that this always is true for the actual plots?  If so, the solution is straightforward.

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE! I hope you will become a regular contributor.  To get started,  1) take the introductory [tour] now, 2) when you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](http://tinyurl.com/ch98nrh), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge, 3) remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, [by clicking the checkmark sign](http://tinyurl.com/4srwe2t), and 4) give help too, by answering questions in your areas of expertise.

Answer (score 2):

The desired minimum value can be obtained from the `ListContourPlot` as follows.  In the absence of specified `data`, use

```
data = Flatten[Table[{x, y, x - (y - 2/3)^2}, {x, 0, 1, .01}, {y, 0, 1, .01}], 1];
```

Next, use `ListContourPlot` to generate a `Mesh` curve corresponding to the desired contour, here `0.5`.  (In principle, a `Contour` curve could be used instead of a `Mesh` curve, but doing so is less convenient.)

```
plt = ListContourPlot[data, Mesh -> {{.5}}, MeshFunctions -> {(#3) &},
   MeshStyle -> Thick, Contours -> 0, FrameLabel -> {x, y}, 
   ImageSize -> Large, LabelStyle -> Directive[Black, Bold, Medium]]
```

[image]

along with a spurious error message that can be ignored.

> Flatten::argb: Flatten called with 0 arguments; between 1 and 3 arguments are expected.Flatten::argb: Flatten called with 0 arguments; between 1 and 3 arguments are expected.

Evidently, `ListContourPlot` does not like `Contours -> 0`.  Next, extract the `Line` corresponding to the curve,

```
lst = Cases[plt[[1]] // Normal, Line[z_] -> z, Infinity][[1]];
```

and determine the minimum point,

```
min = MinimalBy[lst, First] // Last
(* {0.500011, 0.67} *)
```

which visibly is correct.  A sometimes slightly more accurate value can be obtained by

```
int = Interpolation[Reverse /@lst];
FindMinimum[int[y], {y, min // Last}]
(* {0.50001, {y -> 0.670422}} *)
```

Here, it is no better than `min`.

Answer (score 0):

My solution was to first make an interpolating function `f` from the discrete data:

```
vdata=data[[1 ;;,3]];
f = Interpolation[Transpose[{data[[1;;,1;;2]], vdata}], InterpolationOrder -> 1];
```

Then, I made a loop to increment `x` and `y` by `inc` and apply in `f[x,y]` until the contour of interest was reached at minimal x-value `ans`:

```
contour = 0.5;
inc=0.001;
Do[
   v = f[x, y];
   If[v >= contour, {ans = x, Break[]}];
, {x, 0, 1, inc}, {y, 0, 1, inc}];
```

Not efficient, but it worked for my particular problem.

Answer (score 0):

Construct an interpolation function, take its derivative (which results in a new interpolation function), then plot the zero contour of that:

```
data = Flatten[
   Table[{x, y, x - (x/2 + y - 2/3)^2}, {x, 0, 1, .01}, {y, 0, 
     1, .01}], 1];
int = Interpolation[data];
dy = D[int[x, y], y]
Show[{
  ContourPlot[int[x, y], {x, 0, 1}, {y, 0, 1}],
  ContourPlot[dy, {x, 0, 1}, {y, 0, 1}, Contours -> {0}, 
   ContourShading -> False]}]
```

[image]

if you need specific points on the contours, extract that line and interpolate:

```
c = Interpolation[{int[Sequence @@ ##], ##} & /@ (First@
      Cases[Normal@
        ContourPlot[dy, {x, 0, 1}, {y, 0, 1}, Contours -> {0},
         ContourShading -> False] , Line[pts_] :> pts , Infinity])];
Show[{
  ContourPlot[int[x, y], {x, 0, 1}, {y, 0, 1},
   Epilog -> {Red, PointSize[.025], 
     Point[Table[c[v], {v, 0, 1, .2}]]}]}]
```

[image]

note this is a little different input example than the other answer.